# What does the subindex $x$ in $\text{Bi}_{1-x}\text{Sb}_{x}$ mean?

Tags: condensed-matter, notation, topological-insulators, insulators, chemical-compounds

I am currently reworking our condensed matter lecture. We shortly discussed topologic insulaters at the example of

$$\text{Bi}_{1-x}\text{Sb}_{x}$$

I am not sure what the $x$ stands for. Normally the index at an element tells me "how many atoms of that element there are", but in this case we are discussing values of $x = 0.04$ etc. so this does not make sense. I read through some papers but could not find any explanation.

Any idea of what x could mean is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 100% of the medium is composed of the two elements $A$ and $B$, than a easy ways to write the percentages 
$p_A$ and 
$$x=p_B=1-p_A$$
is $A_{p_A}B_{p_B}$.
Thus, in your case it becomes $A_{1-x}B_x$.

Comment: Thanks for that quick and helpful answere!

Answer (score 5):

> Normally the index at an element tells me "how many atoms of that element there are", but in this case we are discussing values of $x = 0.04$ etc. so this does not make sense.

That is still what it means. You just need to beat it with a rubber hammer until it starts making sense.

In this particular instance, for example, it means that four atoms out of every 100 are tin, and the rest are bismuth.

Comment: Thanks! Made my day xD